# ValueError: Shapes (None, 12) and (None, 11) are incompatible when training using keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I've been trying to train a CNN model with a dataset of face images to detect expression but I keep getting error on `model.evaluate` function.

This is the code I'm trying to run (I got it from GitHub):

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import cv2, os
from keras import optimizers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
#from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, MaxPooling2D,Flatten,Dropout,Dense
from tensorflow.keras  import optimizers

from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras.models import load_model
from time import time

K.set_image_data_format('channels_first')

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

def get_image_size():
    img = cv2.imread('dataset/0/1.jpg', 0)
    return img.shape

def get_num_of_classes():
    return len(os.listdir('dataset/'))

image_x, image_y = get_image_size()

def cnn_model():
    num_of_classes = get_num_of_classes()
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (5,5), input_shape=(image_x, image_y, 1), activation='relu', data_format='channels_last'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(10, 10), strides=(10, 10), padding='same'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.6))
    model.add(Dense(num_of_classes, activation='softmax'))
    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-2)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
    filepath="cnn_model_keras.h5"
    checkpoint1 = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint1]
    from keras.utils import plot_model
    plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True)
    return model, callbacks_list

def train():
    with open("train_images", "rb") as f:
        train_images = np.array(pickle.load(f))
    with open("train_labels", "rb") as f:
        train_labels = np.array(pickle.load(f), dtype=np.uint8)

    with open("test_images", "rb") as f:
        test_images = np.array(pickle.load(f))
    with open("test_labels", "rb") as f:
        test_labels = np.array(pickle.load(f), dtype=np.uint8)

    with open("val_images", "rb") as f:
        val_images = np.array(pickle.load(f))
    with open("val_labels", "rb") as f:
        val_labels = np.array(pickle.load(f), dtype=np.uint8)

    train_images = np.reshape(train_images, (train_images.shape[0], image_x, image_y, 1))
    test_images = np.reshape(test_images, (test_images.shape[0], image_x, image_y, 1))
    val_images = np.reshape(val_images, (val_images.shape[0], image_x, image_y, 1))

    train_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(train_labels)
    test_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(test_labels)
    val_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(val_labels)

    model, callbacks_list = cnn_model()
    
    tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="./logs/{}".format(time()))
    
    callbacks_list.append(tensorboard)
    model.fit(train_images, train_labels, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels), epochs=10, batch_size=100, callbacks=callbacks_list)
    model = load_model('cnn_model_keras.h5')
    model.summary()
    model.add(BatchNormalization(),name='new')
    scores = model.evaluate(val_images, val_labels, verbose=1)
    print("CNN Error: %.2f%%" % (100-scores[1]*100))
    
train()
```

images_x, images_y = 100

num_of_classes = 12

Upon running this code I get output:

```
Warning: The `lr` argument is deprecated, use `learning_rate` instead.
  super(SGD, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)
Epoch 1/10
25/25 [==============================] - 4s 61ms/step - loss: 1.1408 - accuracy: 0.6736 - val_loss: 3.1856 - val_accuracy: 0.6560
Epoch 2/10
25/25 [==============================] - 1s 48ms/step - loss: 0.2618 - accuracy: 0.9224 - val_loss: 1.7538 - val_accuracy: 0.7440
Epoch 3/10
25/25 [==============================] - 1s 48ms/step - loss: 0.1514 - accuracy: 0.9604 - val_loss: 0.9787 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
Epoch 4/10
25/25 [==============================] - 1s 47ms/step - loss: 0.0947 - accuracy: 0.9816 - val_loss: 0.5427 - val_accuracy: 0.8760
Epoch 5/10
25/25 [==============================] - 1s 49ms/step - loss: 0.0729 - accuracy: 0.9844 - val_loss: 0.3661 - val_accuracy: 0.8920
Epoch 6/10
25/25 [==============================] - 1s 47ms/step - loss: 0.0577 - accuracy: 0.9872 - val_loss: 0.1958 - val_accuracy: 0.9360
Epoch 7/10
25/25 [==============================] - 7s 292ms/step - loss: 0.0492 - accuracy: 0.9912 - val_loss: 0.1289 - val_accuracy: 0.9640
Epoch 8/10
25/25 [==============================] - 2s 72ms/step - loss: 0.0465 - accuracy: 0.9916 - val_loss: 0.0730 - val_accuracy: 0.9760
Epoch 9/10
25/25 [==============================] - 1s 48ms/step - loss: 0.0385 - accuracy: 0.9908 - val_loss: 0.0421 - val_accuracy: 0.9840
Epoch 10/10
25/25 [==============================] - 1s 48ms/step - loss: 0.0358 - accuracy: 0.9928 - val_loss: 0.0351 - val_accuracy: 0.9840

WARNING:tensorflow:Error in loading the saved optimizer state. As a result, your model is starting with a freshly initialized optimizer.

Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 96, 96, 32)        832

 batch_normalization_1 (Batc  (None, 96, 96, 32)       128
 hNormalization)

 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 10, 10, 32)       0
 2D)

 flatten_1 (Flatten)         (None, 3200)              0

 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 1024)              3277824

 batch_normalization_2 (Batc  (None, 1024)             4096
 hNormalization)

 dropout_1 (Dropout)         (None, 1024)              0

 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 11)                11275

=================================================================
Total params: 3,294,155
Trainable params: 3,292,043
Non-trainable params: 2,112
_________________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\College_Works\Mini Project\emojify\train_cnn_keras.py", line 99, in <module>
    train()
  File "D:\College_Works\Mini Project\emojify\train_cnn_keras.py", line 95, in train
    scores = model.evaluate(val_images, val_labels, verbose=1)
  File "D:\College_Works\Mini Project\emojify\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\WORKSP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filed3rb0agt.py", line 15, in tf__test_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "D:\College_Works\Mini Project\emojify\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1557, in test_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "D:\College_Works\Mini Project\emojify\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1546, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "D:\College_Works\Mini Project\emojify\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1535, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.test_step(data)
    File "D:\College_Works\Mini Project\emojify\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1501, in test_step
        self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "D:\College_Works\Mini Project\emojify\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 948, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "D:\College_Works\Mini Project\emojify\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "D:\College_Works\Mini Project\emojify\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 139, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "D:\College_Works\Mini Project\emojify\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 243, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "D:\College_Works\Mini Project\emojify\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 1787, in categorical_crossentropy
        return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    File "D:\College_Works\Mini Project\emojify\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5119, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 12) and (None, 11) are incompatible
```

I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: What is the shape of `val_images` and `val_labels` when you reach the `evaluate()` method?

Comment: Not sure how to get shape but if its something like: `print(np.shape(val_images))` then its (250, 100, 100, 1) - val_images, (250, 12) - val_labels @Djinn

Comment: Looks like your labels have an extra class compared to your final dense layer. Remember, it's 0-indexed, so a value of 1 means there are two classes (the 0 and 1 class). You're passing labels with 13 classes (including 0) when your model is expecting 12.

Comment: you are having 12 classes so in the output dense layer there should be 12 neurons.

Comment: oh thats why.. thanks a lot :)